# Filtering traffic between ports on an ethernet switch

Tags: switch, access-control-list, ethernet

I would like to know if there is a standard way of limiting traffic between ports on a managed Ethernet switch? I have a 7-port Ethernet switch (microchip - KSZ9897), which is a layer 2 switch, but with IEEE 802.1X (ACL) and 802.1Q (VLAN) support. What I specifically need is the following:

I need to only allow traffic from port 1 to 2 for one specific IP address. The same from port 2 to port 1, one specific IP address. Port 2 will also need to forward traffic to ports 3-7, using an alias IP address.

Could this be done using ACL or another method? All hosts are on the same subnet, as there are no routers in the system, and I am not able to add a router.

Answer (score 3):

Switching is Layer 2 functionality and  the kind of ACL you want to create should be acting on Layer 3, the IP layer with IP-addresses en Port numbers.

Therefore *"a **standard** way of limiting traffic between ports on a managed Ethernet switch"* does not exist.

Having said that, many managed L2 switches are more capable but there is no standard/universal way of configuring them.

Note that the datasheet for your device suggest that L3 ACL's  are supported in your hardware : https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/KSZ9897R-Data-Sheet-DS00002330D.pdf says the following:

> **section §4.4.16 ACCESS CONTROL LIST (ACL) FILTERING**
>
> An Access Control List (ACL) can be created for each port to perform filtering on incoming layer 2 MAC, layer 3 IP or
> layer 4 TCP/UDP packets. Multicast filtering is handled in the Static Address Table and the Reserved Multicast Address
> Table, but the ACL provides additional capabilities for filtering routed network protocols. As shown in Figure 4-3, ACL
> filtering may take precedence over other forwarding functions.
> The ACL allows the switch to filter ingress traffic based on the following header fields:
>
> - Source or destination MAC address and/or EtherType
> - Source or destination IPv4 address with programmable mask
> - IPv4 protocol
> - Source or destination UDP port
> - Source or destination TCP port
> - TCP Flag with programmable mask
>
> The ACL is implemented as an ordered list of up to 16 access control rules which are programmed into the ACL Table.
> Each entry specifies certain rules (a set of matching conditions and action rules) to control the forwarding and priority
> of packets. When a packet is received on an interface, the switch compares the fields in the packet against any applied
> ACLs to verify that the packet has the permissions required to be forwarded, based on the conditions specified in the
> lists. Multiple match conditions can be either AND'ed or OR'ed together.

No idea though how you can actually use that though.